# Как получить список объектов класса?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть класс в котором имеются объекты, есть ли возможность получить список этих объектов, не считая способа когда я сам создаю список и добавляю объекты в него?

Пример

```
class Example(ExampleAbstract):
    obj1 = '1000321'
    obj2 = 10
    obj3 = SomethingClass.something_method
```

Comment: Из примера не очень понятно, что всё-таки вам нужно - список объектов, инстанцированных от этого класса? Или список объектов, которые являются аттрибутами класса?

Comment: Аттрибутами класса

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все атрибуты класса можно увидеть с помощью специального метода `__dict__`. Правда, туда кроме явно созданных Вами атрибутов попадут и системные атрибуты, но их легко отфильтровать, т.к. их название начинается и заканчивается двойным подчёркиванием:

```
print(
    {k: v for k, v in Example.__dict__.items()
     if not (k.startswith('__') and k.endswith('__'))
})
```

UPD на комментарий:

Имея название атрибута, вы всегда можете, как получить его значение

```
value = getattr(Example, k)
print(value)
```

так и заменить его на новое значение:

```
setattr(Example, k, new_value_obj)
```

Comment: Этот метод, на сколько я понимаю, вернет названия аттрибутов в виде строк и не получится их применять таким образом Example.k

Comment: @Jhartum я дополнил мой ответ

Comment: спасибо большое